# Assignment to an undeclared variable throws ReferenceError in Node only when using ECMAScript modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I have the a file `index.js` with these contents:

```
const test = function (cb) { cb(); };
test(myCallback = function () { console.log('done'); });
```

When I run `index.js` using Node v16.6.1 and CommonJS:

```
done
```

When I run `index.js` using Node v16.6.1 with `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` file:

```
ReferenceError: myCallback is not defined
```

Can you tell me whether and how this relates to ECMAScript modules?

Comment: That is *not* a "named callback function".

Comment: @Bergi is it not a named function expression?

Comment: No. `test(function myCallback() { … })` is a named function expression. You have an assignment to an undeclared variable, which is what nodejs is (rightly) complaining about.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, that is obvious is hindsight. I fooled myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side effect from using ESM. Strict mode (`use strict`) is enable by default. Which cause the error, because: `myCallback` [isn't declared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#converting_mistakes_into_errors) anywhere.

```
let myCallback;
test(myCallback = function () { console.log('done'); }); // here we assign myCallback to a function. are you sure you want to actually do this?
```

Before, you were attempting to create a global variable.

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global variables. [...] Assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead throw an error in strict mode

Comment: Nice summary what strict mode means [is here](/a/27114400)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to name functions. You can set a variable equal to a function. Or you can give a function a name. Here are two ways to solve your problem

Name the function

```
test(function myCallback () { console.log('done'); });
```

Set variable equal to function

```
const myCallback = function () { console.log('done'); }
test(myCallback);
```